# How to Shoot a Laser?

Tags: c, struct, sdl

I've been learning C and am trying to play with SDL to shake things up a bit. I want to make a simple space shooter where the space bar causes the player's little ship to fire a laser.

My current thought process on how this would work is there will be a "Laser" struct, which contains the sprite surface and the sprite rectangle.

```
struct Laser {
    SDL_Surface *sprite;
    SDL_Rect rcSprite;
};
```

Now I need a function which creates my "Laser" structure. It will allocate memory, load the .BMP sprite image and set the starting position of the laser. It will then return a pointer to the newly created struct.

```
struct Laser *fireLaser(char *sprite, int x, int y) {
    struct Laser *l = malloc(sizeof(struct Laser));
    assert(l != NULL);

    l->sprite = loadImage(sprite);
    l->rcSprite.x = x;
    l->rcSprite.y = y;

    return l;
}
```

Now the idea is to have the laser fire when the space bar is pressed. Following how I *think* this would work, that means the "fireLaser" function will need to be called for EACH laser fired.

```
if(keystate[SDLK_SPACE]) {
    lasers[i] = fireLaser("laser.bmp", player->rcSprite.x, player->rcSprite.y);
    drawLaser(lasers[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

The above code would call the "drawLaser" function, handing off to it the newly created Laser struct.

```
void drawLaser(struct Laser *laser) {
    while(laser->rcSprite.y > 0) {
        SDL_BlitSurface(laser->sprite, NULL, screen, &laser->rcSprite);
        laser->rcSprite.y -= 1;
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen when I run this is I'll hold the space bar down, and since there is no *frequency of fire*, a steady stream will be drawn from the ship going up.

The code compiles, but when I run it and press the space bar, a straight white as predicted is drawn, but the program crashes (segmentation fault)! I found (mostly by accident) that if I re-write the code to set my index variable "*i*" back to 0 (show below) after the struct is made, the program will not crash.

```
if(keystate[SDLK_SPACE]) {
    i = 0;
    lasers[i] = fireLaser("laser.bmp", player->rcSprite.x, player->rcSprite.y);
    drawLaser(lasers[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

Now I get a long white line being drawn vertically across the screen.

I'm sure this is probably not a very good way doing this, but I started down this path and I'm trying to see it through! The questions I have now are, why is it that I need to reset the "*i*" variable, or else the program crashes? Also I have to ask if this is at all an effective way of accomplishing firing a laser. Am I on the right path, or should I just stop and reevaluate?

Comment: Well, how big is `lasers`? And what happens when `i` gets bigger than that?

Comment: It's a good idea to start simple, and work your way up to the more complex. For example, start with a blank screen add one sprite at a known location. Make sure it looks right. Then move the sprite in response to a keypress. In other words, remove the `while` from the `drawLaser` function, and just draw the sprite and update its position. Make sure the sprite moves the way you expect. Once you have one sprite working with manually controlled movement, then you can move on to automatic movement, and finally automatic movement of multiple sprites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can't give you a precise answers because I can't know the whole code, I can explain how it should work and how your differs from a normal approach.

A normal game loop works sort of this way:

```
while (!exiting) {
  render();
  logic();
  events();
}
```

Now, `render()` should draw things, `logic()` should move things and `events()` should poll for external input (eg. keyboard) and modify things accordingly.

In your code you are drawing the laser in the `events()` part of the code. Which is not correct, you are mixing things. A good design would be something like:

```
static size_t MAX_LASERS = 50;
static size_t laserCount;
static laser* lasers;

void setup()
{
  lasers = calloc(MAX_LASERS, sizeof(laser));
  laserCount = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < laserCount; ++i)
    drawLaser(lasers[i]);
}

void logic()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < laserCount; ++i)
  {
    moveLaser(lasers[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < laserCount; ++i)
  {
    if (outsideScreen(lasers[i])
      removeLaser(lasers[i])
  }
}

void events() 
{
  ...
  if(keystate[SDLK_SPACE]) {
    if (laserCount < MAX_LASERS)
      laser[laserCount++] = generateLaser(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing missing here is the concept of time. To effectively animate objects on the screen, either the `events` function needs to wait for a timed event before returning, or the `logic` function needs to be time aware. And normally `logic` runs before `render` so that the most up-to-date info is used in `render`.

Comment: @user3386109: I explicitly excluded time because it comes later and would complicate things, actually the best approach would be to have a `delayForFPS()` function inside the game loop which will purposely wait an amount of time so that each game loop update takes the same amount of time (so you can obtain a fixed frame per second value). In addition `void logic()` would become `void logic(float dt)` to take in account how much time has been passed since last logic update, to have a system which "moves" at the same speed regardless how many frames per seconds are rendered.

Comment: Fair enough, the only reason I brought it up is because of the `while` loop in the OP's `drawLaser` function, which clearly needs to be time aware. As is, it could blit the sprite hundreds of times in a single frame (depending on `y` of course).

Comment: Thanks Jack, this is just what I needed to set me on the right path :)